# Why was System.ServiceModel.Persistence made obsolete?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, persistence, service-model

I'm looking into creating a custom persistence provider for WCF, but [according](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.persistence%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to MSDN, this entire assembly was made obsolete. I can't seem to find a reason for this, or recommendations as to what should be used in its stead. Can anyone tell me why this was made obsolete and what I can use as a replacement?

Answer (score 4):

Every section of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.persistence%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you linked says:

> The WF3 types are deprecated.  Instead, please use the new WF4 types from System.Activities.*

More info from [Jurgen Willis, MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/workflowteam/archive/2012/02/08/deprecatingwf3.aspx):

> In .NET 4 the Workflow Team released an all new Workflow engine in the System.Activities namespace.  This new Workflow technology, which we refer to as WF4, responded to key customer feedback by providing significant programming model, runtime, and authoring enhancements.
>
> With the release of .NET 4.5 Beta we are marking the types in the “WF3”, System.Workflow, namespace as obsolete.
>
> Customers who want to migrate their applications to WF4 will find help in the [WF 4 Migration Guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264175%28VS.100%29.aspx) articles on MSDN and the [WF Migration Kit](http://wf.codeplex.com/releases/view/41401) on the [WF CodePlex](http://wf.codeplex.com/) site.